# Swing form gets freezed

Tags: java, swing

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#opengl
I set the system property as following in order to JVM uses the gpu opengl hw acceleration  if available.
there is no crash, and the verbose message says the pipeline is activated `OpenGL pipeline enabled for default config on screen 0`.

```
        public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "True");
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new WindowsClassicLookAndFeel());
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RootForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        //no difference
//        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
//            public void run() {
//                new RootForm().setVisible(true);
//            }
//        });
        //no difference
//        new Thread(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//                new RootForm().setVisible(true);                
//            }
//        }).start();
    }
```

but the swing form gets freezed! even `repaint()` call doesn't work.
What is the problem would be?
Platform: Win7X64, GPU: AMD HD5870 (updated driver).
Thanks in advance.
**EDIT**
I tried it several times and I got it work. and no the new problem. it works randomly. very weird. works whenever it wants.

Comment: Do you have an example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: OH! so weird, it's working now, it sounds like a bug, I just skip set the look and feel to windows and reverse it again, now it's working. is there any known bug about this? @MadProgrammer

Comment: There is no known bug for removing and replacing the exact same code. I'd imagine it was an error with your IDE.

Comment: I just tested this property with another small-simple swing app and it worked, then give another try with freezed frame and problem solved, what kinda error does IDE(Eclipse) would have about this? @christopher

Comment: check edit dear @MadProgrammer

Comment: *"it works randomly. very weird"* Event Dispatching Thread issue? Do you initialize your GUI using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` method? Just as described in [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) article.

Comment: @dic19 yes exactly using `SwingUtilities#invokeLater()`

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestOpenGL {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "True");
        new TestOpenGL();
    }

    public TestOpenGL() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int yPos = 0;
        private int yDelta = 2;
        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel("Bouncy, Bouncy...");
            add(label);
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    yPos += yDelta;
                    if (yPos > getHeight()) {
                        yPos = getHeight();
                        yDelta *= -1;
                    } else if (yPos < 0) {
                        yPos = 0;
                        yDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    label.setText("Bouncy, Bouncy...@ " + yPos);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            int x = (getWidth() - 2) / 2;
            g2d.drawOval(x, yPos - 2, 4, 4);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help dear, but honestly it's working unreliable(randomly) here. is it possible that it's a HW thing? because I know I have million of problems in my OS here.

Comment: @parsaporahmad It's highly possible. I've seen some issues with Video Card drivers which had us playing around with a number of settings including `sun.java2d.accthreshold=0` and `sun.java2d.d3d=false`, set on the command line (using `-D`). Look up those values before you try them...

Comment: *"..it's working unreliable(randomly) here."*  By 'it' DYM your code, or the code in this answer, or both?

Comment: @AndrewThompson both dear, both